# iPad - landscape orientation is not working on iPad, but working in simulator

Tags: ios, ipad

We used following code to align one of screen in landscape mode

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:     
    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    }
```

It shows as expected in 5.1 simulator(in landscape), but shows in portrait mode
 in iPad. Pl suggest

Comment: Is your iPad on iOS 6.0 by any chance? Or is its rotation locked? (do other apps rotate?)

Comment: Filip. You are correct. Its iPad 6.0. Aint 6.0 supposed to support functionality working on 5.1? Pl suggest

Comment: Is this a modal screen that's presented while its parent is still being created and presented (i.e. in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`)?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the problem that Filip refers to.

However, another problem I've noticed with real hardware — even without iOS 6 involved — is that the ordering is slightly different.

If you are trying to a modal view controller from a view controller *before it's fully processed its own rotation*, the modal view controller will appear in portrait mode. The first view controller hasn't fully handled its own rotation until events are processed for it.

In other words, if you try to present a modal view controller from an early event in a view controller (such as `viewWillAppear`) it will always show up in portrait mode.

To fix this, instead of presenting the view controller immediately, just schedule it to the main loop using a block.

Change the line that invokes the view controller, which might look something like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"firstRun" sender: self];
```

To:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"firstRun" sender: self];
});
```

If you're using another method to present the new view controller, try the same approach with it: wrap it in a `dispatch_async` to the main queue so it's done later.